# Need help combining counter with recurring Collatz Conjecture

Tags: python

I am trying to combine a function that calculates the collatz sequence for a given integer and creates a running total based on the first digit of each number in the sequence. The sequence would then reset until reaching the starting integer is 1. The purpose of this is to compare the final counts for each integer 1-9 to compare to Benford's Law.

The code that I have written is below.

Mark, thanks for your help! I completely overlooked the missing =. I have corrected the code and am still getting a few type errors, but I will work on those.

```
#Sets count to 0
count_1=0
count_2=0
count_3=0
count_4=0
count_5=0
count_6=0
count_7=0
count_8=0
count_9=0

# basic Collatz Conjecture
def collatz(n):
    first_num=(n[0])
    if first_num == 1:
        count_1=+1
    elif first_num == 2:
        count_2=+1
    elif first_num == 3:
        count_3=+1  
    elif first_num == 4:
        count_4=+1    
    elif first_num == 5:
        count_5=+1    
    elif first_num == 6:
        count_6=+1    
    elif first_num == 7:
        count_7=+1    
    elif first_num == 8:
        count_8=+1
    elif first_num == 9:
        count_9=+1
    while n > 1:
        if (n % 2):
            # n is odd
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            # n is even
            n = n//2
            
def aggregate(x):
    if x > 1:
        n=x
        collatz(n)
        x=x-1
    else:
        count_1=+1
        print("Count 1 is: ", count_1)
        print("Count 2 is: ", count_2)
        print("Count 3 is: ", count_3)
        print("Count 4 is: ", count_4)
        print("Count 5 is: ", count_5)
        print("Count 6 is: ", count_6)
        print("Count 7 is: ", count_7)
        print("Count 8 is: ", count_8)
        print("Count 9 is: ", count_9)
    
x = int(input('Enter x: '))
aggregate(x)
```

Comment: `first_num = 1` is an assignment. `first_num == 1` is a comparison.

Comment: On a side note, rather than having 9 separate counter variables, it may be cleaner just to keep a list.

Comment: For future posts, please try to keep the original text of the question, and communicate through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise way of achieving what you want (not exactly an "answer" but I'm posting it in case you can benefit from it)

```
leftmost_digit = {str(d): 0 for d in range(0,10)}
def collatz_with_aggregation(n: int) -> None:
    while n != 1:
        # print(n, end=" ")
        leftmost_digit[str(n)[0]] += 1
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = int(n / 2)
        else:
            n = 3*n +1

for n in range(2, 100):
    collatz_with_aggregation(n)
    # print("")

for digit, value in leftmost_digit.items():
    print(f"{digit}: {value}")
```

and aggregating for 100 will give you:

```
$ python collatz.py 
0: 0
1: 883
2: 584
3: 321
4: 427
5: 282
6: 116
7: 166
8: 210
9: 128
```